# Attach multiple Roles or Profiles to an instance

Tags: amazon-web-services

What's the limit for roles to a single instance?  I see there's a limit of 20 policies per role and my policies are very granular.

Can I have multiple roles or multiple profiles attached to my one instance?

I believe the answer is no and that my present design is blocked by AWS for a very good reason which means I need to rethink the policies.  I'm using terraform modules and a policy per module seemed like a good separation of concerns but AWS seems to disagree.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [Terraform Docs](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/r/iam_instance_profile.html) an instance can have 1 profile linking 1 role to the instance (up to 20 policies -> 1 profile -> 1 roles -> many instances).  So, if there are too many policies you can follow on of these paths:

- split the responsibilities across different group of instances with a different role assigned to each group.  This will allow 20 policies attached to group A's instance role and 20 other policies attached to group B's instance role.
- consolidate the many smaller policies into a fewer larger policies which are then attached to a role which becomes the instance role via a profile.

> roles - (Deprecated) A list of role names to include in the profile. The current default is 1. If you see an error message similar to Cannot exceed quota for InstanceSessionsPerInstanceProfile: 1, then you must contact AWS support and ask for a limit increase. WARNING: This is deprecated since version 0.9.3 (April 12, 2017), as >= 2 roles are not possible. See issue #11575.

Comment: Correct, except you have one typo: "or the *policies* need to be consolidated" should be "or the *profiles* need to be consolidated".  You can assign multiple policies to an EC2 server, since a role can have multiple policies assigned to it. You can't however assign multiple profiles to an EC2 server.

Comment: Thanks, I'm a bit of a nightmare on a keyboard