# Performance Test - Upload dashboards to s3

Tags: jmeter

I wanted to upload my JMeter dashboards to s3. The JMeter tests are run in EC2 instances. I would like to use IAM roles instead of an access key to upload the dashboards to s3 for security reasons.
I went through this page where files are uploaded using access key using HTTP requests.
https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-handle-dynamic-aws-sigv4-in-jmeter-for-api-testing
can the same be achieved through I am roles instead of access key or do I need to import java class to upload files using s3 client, instanceprofilecredentials provider, and processor

Answer (score 0):

Here is something you can try:

1. Create Role:

   `aws iam create-role --role-name <PerfTest-EC2-Role-Name> --assume-role-policy-document '{"Version":"2012-10-17","Statement":[{"Sid":"","Effect":"Allow","Principal":{"Service": "ec2.amazonaws.com"},"Action":"sts:AssumeRole"}]}'`
2. Add Role to EC2 Instance Profile:

   `aws iam add-role-to-instance-profile --instance-profile-name <JMeter-EC2-InstanceProfile-ID> --role-name <PerfTest-EC2-Role-Name>`
3. Grant the Role S3 permissions:

   ```
   cat << EOF > BucketPolicy.json
   {
       "Version": "2012-10-17",
       "Statement": [
           {
               "Sid": "PublicReadGetObject",
               "Effect": "Allow",
               "Principal": "*",
               "Action": [
                   "s3:GetObject"
               ],
               "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::<Bucket-Name>/*"
           },
           {
               "Sid": "ServiceRoleWriteObject",
               "Effect": "Allow",
               "Principal": {
                   "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::<Client-ID>:role/<PerfTest-EC2-Role-Name>"
               },
               "Action": [
                   "s3:DeleteObject",
                   "s3:PutObject"
               ],
               "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::<Bucket-Name>/*"
           }
       ]
   }
   EOF

   aws s3api put-bucket-policy --bucket <Bucket-Name> --policy file://BucketPolicy.json
   ```

If 2. above fails with
`Cannot exceed quota for InstanceSessionsPerInstanceProfile: 1`
you can look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54184769/attach-multiple-roles-or-profiles-to-an-instance/54184839).

Comment: I have already attached the role to EC2 and policy to the s3 bucket and am able to put the object to s3 through the java class. my question was the same be achieved through HTTP request in JMeter assuming the role instead of access key in that case what would be the header as stated in the below page https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-handle-dynamic-aws-sigv4-in-jmeter-for-api-testing

Comment: @sman sorry I misunderstood and thanks for clarifying.
Perhaps edit your question and add your code that works with the Java classes?
This way it may be easier to figure out if there is an HTTP/REST API equivalent solution.
Maybe also state the reason why you do not want to use the Java classes (or any other SDK)?

Comment: @sman ok, got it. The working code may help to answer your question, so I'd suggest you add the code to your question.